# Obtener la coordenada (en pixels) de un Click en un Div con JS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una **cuadrícula** *(en una imagen)* con **líneas rectas** y **diagonales** similar a la siguiente:

```
___________________________
____/____/____/____/____/__
___/____/____/____/____/___
__/____/____/____/____/____
_/____/____/____/____/____/
/____/____/____/____/____/_
```

Esa cuadrícula está dentro de un **DIV** con tamaño fijo, y el tema es que necesito **sacar la coordenada en píxeles** *(u otros)* para poder calcular en qué cuadro se ha hecho el click *(Esto último sé cómo hacerlo)*.

Como he mencionado, la cuadrícula está en una imágen, y ésta a su vez encima de una cámara en vivo, por lo que no se puede hacer ningún `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si es lo que necesitas pero te puede ayudar a sacar alguna idea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script>
     
     function getPos(e){
      x=e.clientX;
      y=e.clientY;
      cursor="La posicion del mouse es : " + x + " and " + y ;
      document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML=cursor
     }
    
     function stopTracking(){
      document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML="";
     }
    
     </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div id="focusArea" onmousemove="getPos(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking()"><p>Pasa el mouse por aqui para capturar la posición</p></div>
     
     <p id="displayArea"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y en un cuadro podría ser así

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div onmousemove="showCoords(event)" onmouseout="clearCoor()"></div>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coor = "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
}

function clearCoor() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

: